# Declaring library activity in manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library

I seem to have some problems with declaring an android activity from a different package (imported jar library in the `libs` folder) in my applications manifest...

The libraries package is `com.keyes.youtube` and the activity in it is `com.keyes.youtube.OpenYoutubePlayerActivity`.

However, when I try to declare the activity in my apps manifest this way:

```
<activity
       android:name="com.keyes.youtube.OpenYoutubePlayerActivity">
</activity>
```

I get an error that the activity is not setup when trying to launch the activity from the app.

I have also setup the library in the apps manifest like this:

`<uses-library android:name="com.keyes.youtube" android:required="true" />`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yo do not need to add the Library's Activity in your AndroidManfiest.xml. The Library, has its own AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: It actually has not.. It has only a few `.class` files in it. Please see my updated post for more info